# IS IT Possible to Scan LAN or Wi-fi connected Scanner Machine?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs

is it Possible to SCAN physical pages [LAN connected or Wi-fi enabled Scanner machine] using Jquery or asp.net or Jangler, 
**old solution Alt + IPS on word it is for manual scanning**,
**but my requirement automated like Printer kind of access permission**, in office everyone could access that Scanner with simple way, they can view scanning details ever

Comment: No, the webserver does not have access to the client LAN/Wifi (for obvious security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

yes, that is possible by color Network ScanGear 2 Tool, just install it and open the color network scan Gear application then scan your data